# bash warning: delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOL')

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script that contains the following at the end of the file (only followed by an empty line):

```
wget https://downloads.rclone.org/rclone-current-linux-amd64.zip -P /mnt/backend/
unzip /mnt/backend/rclone-current-linux-amd64.zip

cat >/mnt/backend/rclone.conf<<EOL
[remote]
type = s3
provider = AWS
env_auth = false
access_key_id = key
secret_access_key = key
region = us-west-2
storage_class = STANDARD
EOL
```

and when I run it, I get the following warning **my_script.sh: line 40: warning: here-document at line 30 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOL')**

Why is this, I obviously have `EOL`, I've tried to add a back tick preceeding or an apostrophe following it but no go either... what am I missing?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this in `bash`, it works as expected.

Comment: Try running `cat -vet my_script.sh` and look for nonprintable characters such as `EOL^M`.

Comment: Hm, weird... there's no non-printable chars I can see

Comment: Is there a space after `EOL`?

Comment: @thatotherguy no, no space after EOL

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the code from your post into a new file in a new directory and trying it again?

Comment: Does your script have a terminating newline? (It should: On Windows, CRLF sequences _separate_ lines, so you don't need one after the last line; but on UNIX, LFs _terminate_ lines, so you need one after each line for it to be valid).

Comment: If your actual code contains quoted strings or backquotes or `$(...)` rather than `key`, check that quotes, backquotes, and parentheses are balanced.

Answer (score 1):

start with simplest context

```
#!/bin/bash


cat >tst.conf<<EOL
HELLO CAT WORKS
EOL
```

and extend the script, add line by line
, it will tell you where the cause is :_)